# Airflow dag run at exact time

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have some DAGs in airflow that I wanna to execute in a exact time (like 9:05 every day exactly) and not between a interval date. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [cron expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for your DAG's `schedule_interval`.

```py
dag = DAG(..., schedule_interval="5 9 * * *", ...)
```

A great tool to check cron expressions is [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#5_9_*_*_*).

[This guide](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/scheduling-in-airflow/) discusses scheduling in Airflow more broadly too.